# Creating two colums from rows of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table along with few other columns:

```
months    amount
-----------------
 Jan       100
 Feb       200
 Jan       400
```

I want to create a view with this table so that it be like this:

```
Jan    Feb
--------------------
100    200
400    0
```

I searched for it and got PL/SQL solutions cant it be done with only SQL queries ?
Thank You

Comment: What version of SQL you using?  If you know the columns and 2008+ you can use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: actually it is for PostgreSQL

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html - is Crosstab available?

Comment: @MikeMiller cross tab wont do it will give output as
Jan 100 400
Feb 200 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure, you have Crosstab available

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

To get the crosstable you want you need at least three columns

eg:

```
name    months    amount
-------------------------
Helga    Jan       100
Helga    Feb       200
Bernd    Jan       400
```

Then you create your Crosstable like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   crosstab('SELECT name, month, amount from temp')
 AS ct(name varchar, jan int, feb int);

name       jan       feb
--------------------------
Helga     100        200
Bernd     400
```

If you are going to have columns for each month, stick to the example as described in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)

```
create table sales(year int, month int, qty int);
insert into sales values(2007, 1, 1000);
insert into sales values(2007, 2, 1500);
insert into sales values(2007, 7, 500);
insert into sales values(2007, 11, 1500);
insert into sales values(2007, 12, 2000);
insert into sales values(2008, 1, 1000);

select * from crosstab(
  'select year, month, qty from sales order by 1',
  'select m from generate_series(1,12) m'
) as (
  year int,
  "Jan" int,
  "Feb" int,
  "Mar" int,
  "Apr" int,
  "May" int,
  "Jun" int,
  "Jul" int,
  "Aug" int,
  "Sep" int,
  "Oct" int,
  "Nov" int,
  "Dec" int
);
 year | Jan  | Feb  | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov  | Dec
------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------
 2007 | 1000 | 1500 |     |     |     |     | 500 |     |     |     | 1500 | 2000
 2008 | 1000 |      |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your logic, how would SQL know that it should be

```
Jan     Feb
100     200
400     0
```

and not

```
Jan     Feb
400     200
100     0
```

I have taken this to mean that the columns should be in ascending order, (Except for where the value is 0 because there is not enough data):

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Month, Amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Amount) AS RowNumber
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  COALESCE(Jan.Amount, 0) AS Jan,
        COALESCE(Feb.Amount, 0) AS Feb,
        COALESCE(Mar.Amount, 0) AS Mar
FROM    (   SELECT  RowNumber, Amount
            FROM    CTE
            WHERE   Month = 'Jan'
        ) jan
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  RowNumber, Amount
            FROM    CTE
            WHERE   Month = 'Feb'
        ) feb
            ON feb.RowNumber = Jan.RowNumber
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  RowNumber, Amount
            FROM    CTE
            WHERE   Month = 'Mar'
        ) Mar
            ON Mar.RowNumber = Jan.RowNumber
```

This logic has been tested in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a51a0/1), however I am fairly sure you can apply the use of Rownumber to CROSSTAB to get around the problems you are currently having with CROSSTAB. RowNumber becomes your rowvalue, I have never used Crosstab in postgres but I think you would end up with something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    CROSSTAB('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Amount) AS RowNumber, Month, Amount FROM T',
                 'SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Amount) AS RowNumber FROM  T') 
        AS (RowNumber INT, Jan INT, Feb INT, Mar INT);
```

I can't get this working on SQL Fiddle, but I think it is because CROSSTAB isn't enabled as even the example in the Postgres docs doesn't work on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: BTW - I've just now added the crosstab function to sql fiddle.